# Rails:2 insert record in two db on clicking one submit button (save record of one controller in other controller )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, save

I have 2 models that correspond to 2 separate db tables.
one is `task` and other is `bookedhour`

Relationship is like

```
Task: has_many booked_hours
BookedHour: belongs_to Task
```

To create a task it needs **booked hours** from the model `BookedHour` for that task. It is in the form of new task and for that `attr_accessor` is declare in task model.
Now I want to store that **task** and **booked hours** on saving the task.(basically I want to save the new `task` and `bookedHours` in single click )

I use the following code in create method of task but it did't work.
I write this line after saving the `task(@task.save)`

```
BookedHour.create(:user_id => @user_id, :project_id => session[:actual_project].id, :hours_booked => params[:task][:spend_today])
```

I got following in console and not save record for `bookedhours` but it successfully save new task.

```
BookedHour Columns (0.7ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `booked_hours`      
  SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN     
  SQL (0.0ms)   ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Instead of using BookedHour.create, does @task.booked_hours.build help?

Comment: not working no record in bookedhours

Answer (score 1):

Create won't actually save the record to the database, you need create! to create and save.

Also there's nowhere in the BookedHour.create that you're associating the task record to the booked hour record.

Try the following:

```
BookedHour.create!(
  :task_id => @task.id, 
  :user_id => @user_id, 
  :project_id => session[:actual_project].id, 
  :hours_booked => params[:task][:spend_today]
)
```

Comment: `create` will actually do exactly the same as `create!`, with the only difference of returning `false` instead of raising an exception in case of failure.

Comment: Got error ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (translation missing: nl.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid):

Comment: This is because the record is invalid. Set the default_locale to english to avoid translations problems and rerun.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
@task.booked_hours.create!(:user_id => @user_id, 
                           :project_id => session[:actual_project].id, 
                           :hours_booked => params[:task][:spend_today])
```

If there is a problem (and there is one if the transaction rolls back) you'll see the exception, and you will be able to solve it.

Could you post the validation part of the BookedHour class? (all lines starting with "belongs_to", "validate_..." and "validates" in the class definition)

Comment: got the same error 

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (translation missing: nl.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid):

Comment: set the locale to english or load dutch I18n files.

Comment: Of course, but the error should show the reason for the record to be invalid.